# Input validation - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, validation

Hello guys here is my code for a random password generator;

```
import string
import random
wt = input('Strength of the password: ')
while wt in (1,2,3):
    if wt == 1:
        pword = random.choice(['helloworld','environment','superman','textbook','sandwich','light','sparrow'])

    elif wt == 2:
        pword = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for i in range(8))

    elif wt == 3:
        pword = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for i in range(8))

    print pword

    break
```

I have been unsuccessful in properly validating the input for wt (try , except block)
Please help me implement input validation for wt.

Comment: [`mkpasswd (..)`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578468-password-generator-mkpasswd/)

Comment: I think 'wt' implies complexity here. You may use a regular expression to ensure that the password contains a minimum or a lower case, an upper case, a special char and a number. And add a check using len to meet the minimum password length requirement.

Comment: What is *input*?

Comment: input is the strength of the password. strength 3 will be more complex than strength 2 and so on.. my query regards to input validation, display appropriate error message if user enters something other than 1, 2, or 3.

Answer (score 0):

Convert input to int :-

```
import string
import random
wt = int(input('Strength of the password: '))
while wt in (1,2,3):
    if wt == 1:
        pword = random.choice(['helloworld','environment','superman','textbook','sandwich','light','sparrow'])

    if wt == 2:
        pword = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for i in range(8))

    if wt == 3:
        pword = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for i in range(8))

    print pword

    break
```